# Java Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a simple part of my code in the process to create a Connect 4 game. I am trying to create and display a 6 by 7 board as such where I can eventually drop X's and O's:

```
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
```

I keep getting an error:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

```
public static void printConnect4Board(){
final int WIDTH = 6;
final int HEIGHT = 7;
int [] [] connect4Board = new int [WIDTH][HEIGHT];
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int w = 0; w < connect4Board.length; w++){
   for(int h = 0; h < connect4Board[w].length; h++){
       System.out.println(connect4Board[w][h] + "|");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Should be `connect4Board[h][w]` on the second-to-last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap your indexes and change from println to print:

```
public static void printConnect4Board(){
    final int WIDTH = 6;
    final int HEIGHT = 7;
    int [] [] connect4Board = new int [WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int h = 0; h < HEIGHT; h++){
        System.out.print("|");
        for(int w = 0; w < WIDTH; w++){
            System.out.print("|");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look again, this doesn't throw any exception

Comment: now the output is:                                                                          0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|

Comment: Ok, this should do it, previous code was printing HxW (7x6) whereas I think OP wanted WxH(6x7).

Comment: It does work, I am just trying to figure out a way to get rid of the zeros from the output and also would like another '|' right before the first zero

Comment: If you don't want the zeros change to: System.out.print("|");

Comment: OK, now that you've fixed it, I've removed my downvote.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it with no zero's.

Comment: Try the new code above, removed the zeros and added | in front on each row